# How i can get Html source code from url and put in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, wget

I have a table in mysql with a list of url and a empty field called html_code.

```
url|html_code
```

Ex. Url http://www.website.com/article1.html

I'd need to take source html code from url and put it in my empty field

Is it possible? (Using php?)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `file_get_contents(url)`, that will download the page for you and set a `string` :

```
$html = file_get_contents(url);
```

Then you can insert the html into you mysql DB

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Note: make sure your PHP config allow you to download remotely: `allow_url_fopen`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php